# how to get ngModel value which is inside of ngFor?

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel

```
<div class="form-horizontal" style="margin:auto;" *ngFor="#cmp of getUser">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Name:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cname" [(ngModel)]="cmp.name"/>
        </div>
    </div>
<button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-button--brand" (click)="updateUser(cmp)">Save</button>
</div>
```

Here, by using ngModel in ngFor I can display data but if I want to update/edit this display data then how to do it?

```
updateUser(){     
    var body=JSON.stringify({

         name:this.cmp.name,
        //what to do here????
    })
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    this.http.post('../update.php?id='+matches['id'],body,{
            headers:headers;
    })
     .map(res => res.json())
     .map((res) => {
                    if (res.success) {
                        this.message = res.message;
                    }
                    else{
                        this.err="Something went wrong";
                    }

        })
        .subscribe(
            data=>this.updUser=JSON.stringify(data),
            error=>alert(error),
            msg=>console.log("done"));
    }
```

In this updateUser function I want to update the data.But when I do that it's showing me error that `cmp` is undefine.So what to do for using the value coming from `[(ngModel)]=cmp.name` in post method???

Comment: What version of Angular 2 are you using? In the latest versions it should be `let cmp of getUser` and not `#cmp`.

Comment: @AlexanderCiesielski I'm using angular2: 2.0.0-beta.14 version

Answer (score 0):

Change the `*ngFor="#cmp of getUser"` to `*ngFor="let cmp of getUser"` and check inside `updateUser` function as below if you are getting value you have changed or not :

```
updateUser(data:any){
  console.log(data);

  // if it works you can add your code here to call API
}
```

Comment: I need to use # otherwise it's show me ngFor is not a native property

Comment: and I didn't get anything in console.log() @ranakrunal9